# Azure API Management "Could not complete the request. Please try again later."

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Whenever I try to test an API (using the Test tab of the API blade) I get 
`Could not complete the request. Please try again later.`

This has been happening on my API Management services for at least two hours.
I've created an additional API Management Service and another subscription (with its own APIM).

I'm on the Consumption tier (which has a 99.9% SLA) and the [Azure Status Page](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status) is showing green across the board. My own personal dashboard (Service Health) is showing `No service issues found`.

This leads me to think it's something I've done.

How do I go about investigating this?

Comment: Which API you have requested for?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron A few which were working yesterday no longer work, including an API which points at https://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net (I followed the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish just as a sanity check). I had created an API pointing at that endpoint 2 weeks ago. That also no longer works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. I was on a VPN which was changing the certificate.

I worked this out by going to the URL in Chrome (rather than requesting from the Azure Portal or Postman). Chrome told me that the connection was not secure which led me to realise it was the effect of the VPN.

```
This server could not prove that it is myapimservice.azure-api.net; 
its security certificate is from *.myworkapimservice.azurewebsites.net. 
This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```